# Make text appear based on key press (give user real time feedback) in psychopy

Tags: python, psychopy

I have a stimulus loop in psychopy that displays images for 4 seconds that subjects make binary decisions about. I would like to give them feedback as to which choice they have made.

I.e.: a image gets displayed for 4 seconds with white 'YES' and 'NO' displayed on either side of it. When the user presses a key, the corresponding word turns red. If they then press a different key, it switches. After 4 seconds, the next image appear with white words.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this? Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Could you post some code please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a custom code component. Add the code component to your routine.

Under the "Each Frame" tab add the following code:

```
if (t >=4) and (t < 8):
    if clear_keys:
        event.getKeys()
        clear_keys = False
    else:
        theseKeys = event.getKeys(keyList=['y', 'n'])
        if 'y' in theseKeys:
            Yes.color = 'red'
            No.color = 'white'
        elif 'n' in theseKeys:
            Yes.color = 'white'
            No.color = 'red'
```

Under the "Begin Experiment" tab add the following code:

```
clear_keys = True
```

You will need to change the Yes and No objects in the script to the names of your text components. You will also need to change the number 4 to the start time of the picture and number 8 to the end time.

[Here is a picture of my trial as an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tidt8.jpg)

Comment: Amazing! What a huge help! Thank you :) I just added >>Yes.color = 'red', Yes.color = 'white' << at the end of the routine to reset the color.

Comment: Slight issue I'm having though, in that while the color resets, if I press a key in the preceding condition (a fixation cross), that key press carries over and makes the corresponding text red in the next frame. Any ideas how I can make it so only key presses that start with the onset of the code can affect the color? Thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: Ok, i think i have now addressed that issue!

Comment: Super useful. Thank you! I also wanted to include the ability to freeze the selection after the first response (or last) so I ended up with this: >> 
if key_resp_demo.status == STARTED:
    if len(theseKeys) > 0: 
        disp_resp.append(theseKeys[0])
        if disp_resp[0] == 'period':
            Yes.color = 'red'
            No.color = 'white'
        elif disp_resp[0] == 'comma':
            Yes.color = 'white'
            No.color = 'red' 
<< with >>
Yes.color = 'white'
No.color = 'white'
disp_resp = [] << in Begin Routine